Why is my gitlab pipeline failing after the terraform plan step in here
Here is my pipeline code for git lab
image: zenika/terraform-aws-cli:latest

stages: [stage_b, stage_c]

before_script:
  - terraform init
  - terraform validate

job1:
  stage: stage_b
  script:
    - source destroyfile_status.txt
    - echo $EXITCODE
    - if [ $EXITCODE -eq 2 ]; then
        terraform plan -out="planfile" -detailed-exitcode;
        exit_status=$?;
        VARIABLE_NAME="EXITCODE";
        echo "$VARIABLE_NAME=$exit_status" > planfile_status.txt;
        if [ $exit_status -eq 0 ]; then
            echo " Apply ran not deploying the instance again";
        elif [ $exit_status -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "The Plan failed";
            exit 1;
        elif [ $exit_status -eq 2 ]; then
            echo "the plan is successful";
            terraform apply "planfile";
        fi
      else
        echo "destroy job failed";
      fi
  rules:
    - if: $MORNINGJOB == "morning"

job3:
  stage: stage_c
  script:
    - sudo chmod +x destroy_instances.sh
    - source createfile_status
    - echo $EXITCODE
    - if [ "$EXITCODE" -eq 2 ]; then
        ./destroy_instances.sh;
      else
        echo "create job failed";
      fi
  rules:
    - if: $EVENINGJOB == "evening"

my pipeline fails right after planstep and not throwing any errors in the logs
"Saved the plan to: planfile
To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
terraform apply "planfile"
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1"
